# ServiceHost is not opening to start listening for messages

Tags: wcf

I have this method that calls and tries to open a service host to listen for    request. It is able to create the service host and enable metadata publishing but it fails when it tries to open the service host.

When it reaches to   host.Open() to is not able to open the service   host so that i send my messages from a client. 
        why is my service not starting?

```
public void startOperator()
    {

        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost/Test");

        // Create the ServiceHost.
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Operator), baseAddress))
        {
            // Enable metadata publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
            // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
            // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
            // by the service.
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Close the ServiceHost.
            host.Close();
        }
```

any help is appreciated  ..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `smb.HttpGetEnabled = true` option as it conflicts with your `net.tcp` binding. After commenting it out, code works for me.

Comment: now I moved the same code and created a console application to use as a host application. but I am getting The type or namespace name 'Operator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). If press F12 I can see the Operator code but I don't understand why I am getting the error. and i have all the references required

Comment: never mind the project I created has its target framework set to .Net frame work Client profile I changed it to .Net frame work only option and build is successful..